# A qusetion about the command of postgreSQL

Tags: psql

I am trying to install the BIGSdb, but I failed to create databases.

I use the following command:

> createdb bigsdb_test_seqdef
>   psql -f seqdef.sql bigsdb_test_seqdef

[image: the guide of creating databases]

But, I always get the following error:

[image: the error]

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Please do not post images. Write the code in your question.

Comment: I have edited this. Thank you very much!

Comment: The database already exists. So, you must have ran the script successfully, or at least partly successfully already. Have you tried just using the database, and seeing if it imported successfully? If it seems broken, you could always type `psql` to get a Postgres command line, and then run the query `drop database bigsdb_test_seqdef;` to delete that database, and then `\q` to exit psql and try your import again.

Comment: I tried that, but failed.like following
`postgres@bl8vbox:~$ psql psql (10.5 (Ubuntu 10.5-1.pgdg14.04+1), server 9.5.13) Type "help" for help.postgres=# drop database bigsdb_test_seqdef postgres-# \q postgres@bl8vbox:~$ createdb bigsdb_test_seqdef createdb: database creation failed: ERROR:  database "bigsdb_test_seqdef" already exists’`

Comment: Are there some thing should install, and I missed them? and what does `psql -f `mean？Thank you very much for your patience.